# bitmap.ToLuminanceImage() is not a method

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, phash

all

I wont use Shipwreck.Phash(https://github.com/pgrho/phash) for image,but I have  trouble with the example:

```
var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(fullPathToImage);
var hash = ImagePhash.ComputeDigest(bitmap.ToLuminanceImage());
```

vs2015 cannot find ToLuminanceImage();

I used net4.5.2.  System.Drawing is v4.0.0

After import all packages,but do nothing.

So , how can i do?

Best wish.

Comment: You are missing a `using Shipwreck.Phash.Bitmaps;`

Comment: You are right.thank you a lot.